# Highchart data does not start with 0 gives error

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I recently encountered a weird issue with HighStock.

Firstly here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/woon123/br0e8mkw/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });
    $('#analytics_line').highcharts('StockChart', {
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Analytics of Deals'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'View Count and Redemption Count'
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            allButtonsEnabled: true,
            buttons: [{
                type: 'month',
                count: 3,
                text: 'Day',
                dataGrouping: {
                    forced: true,
                    units: [
                        ['day', [1]]
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: 'Week',
                dataGrouping: {
                    forced: true,
                    units: [
                        ['week', [1]]
                    ]
                }
            }],
            buttonTheme: {
                width: 60
            },
        },

        yAxis: {
            floor: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Number'
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            dataLabels: {
                visible: true
            },
            series: {
                compare: 'value'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            align: 'right',
            backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 2,
            layout: 'vertical',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
            shadow: true
        },

        series: [{
            id: "First Graph",
            name: "First Graph",
            pointStart: 1444060800000.0,
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            data: [20, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23],
        }, {
            id: "Second Graph",
            name: "Second Graph",
            pointStart: 1444060800000.0,
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            data: [9, 12, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16],
        }, ]
    }, function (chart) {

        // apply the date pickers
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $(chart.container).parent())
                .datepicker();
        }, 0);
    });

    // Set the datepicker's date format
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function () {
            this.onchange();
            this.onblur();
        }
    });
});
```

In this case, First Graph is suppose to be above Second Graph according to the data. When you compare the series, First Graph values are always higher then Second Graph.

However, the graph plotted actually cause First Graph to be below Second graph although when you mouse over the lines, it gives the correct values.

Furthermore, First Graph is suppose to start at 20 but as you can see it starts at 0, and the Y-axis values are wrong as well (0-2.5-5)

However, all these errors can be solved by placing 0 at the start of the data.

For the case of First Graph it is [0, 20, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23] and Second Graph it is [0, 9, 12, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16].

Can anyone advice why is this the case and perhaps provide a solution to allow my data to start with a positive integer rather then 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out the compare on the plotOptions, series

```
series: {
    compare: 'value'
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/br0e8mkw/2/

From the API: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.compare

> Compare the values of the series against the first value in the visible range. The y axis will show percentage or absolute change depending on whether compare is set to "percent" or "value". When this is applied to multiple series, it allows comparing the development of the series against each other. Defaults to undefined.